# Passing a key inside an http.get request so that Spring Boot will recognize it

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

Here is my current GET request in my UserDataService that is sent to my Spring Boot api.

```
getCurrentUser(userName){
        return http.get("/users", userName);
}
```

This is the GET method in my Spring Boot Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "userName") String userName) {
        try {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

            if (userName == null)
                userRepository.findAll().forEach(users::add);
            else
                users.add(userRepository.findByUserName(userName));

            if (users.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

In postman, if I enter a key and a value, it works. Right now, my GET request is only passing in a parameter value. How would I pass a key inside of my http.get request?

Comment: Your api endpoint only expects a request param `userName` in the request. Are you asking for a way to add this in the request from your vue.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data as requestparam in springboot application, you can pass parameter in query by key-value pair.

```
getCurrentUser(userName){
        return http.get("/users?userName=testname");
}
```